# gkSudo fails with critical error

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run gkSudo.  This is my second day as a linux user.

Yesterday I could do

`gksudo gedit`

and input my root password fine.

Today, when I run that, the GUI comes up and asked for my password, however then the program fails to run and all I get is:

```
(gksudo:3262): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_str_has_prefix: assertion `str != NULL' failed
```

I cannot `sudo`, I cannot `su`, I can't do anything.  I am trying to add myself to the sudoers file but I can't even view it without being root.  What can I do?

Comment: what you did from yesterday :) ??

Comment: what is the output of `sudo gedit`, for example?

Comment: Out sounds like you messed up your sudoers file, please follow the steps [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo) to repair your sudo.

Comment: welcome to linux. I'm glad to see we can provide a consistent user experience. If all goes well, you should be able to enjoy a new bug every day...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a problem with your sudoers file. There are other reports of a similar bug [in the debian bugtracker](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=686844).